# X-Wallet IOS restore wallet

Tags: wallet-recovery, ios-wallet

I have a X=Wallet on IOS,my phone screen got ruined so after a week my phone was fixed but my wallet just sat froze unable to send or receive.i uninstalled the app then tried on other iphones to restore wallet by the seed to no avail.Can anyone tell me how to properly restore my X-Wallet and on what device i do it on please help me,When i try to restore existing wallet on a Iphone it does nothing ive tried to put the words in every way but after putting in seed you are suppose to hit return after each single word which there is no return on Iphone only enter,

Answer (score 2):

From the XWallet website:

> Recovery
>   A standard 25 word mnemonic format means you can recover directly into the Monero reference client.

So just download the official Monero client (GUI or CLI), sync the blockchain and recover wallet from seed.